# Mysql ORDER BY or GROUP BY for newsfeed

Tags: mysql, database, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to create something like Facebook newsfeed: a person who follows other persons see their last posts at the top. I use this query as db select query but it has some problem.

Does anyone have any idea to improve this query?

These are important tables for this query:

```
 ______
| wall |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
postID | inserterID | sportID | catID | title|insertDate|context|abstraction|editeDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|follower|
---------------------
ID | foerID | foingID
---------------------

SELECT wall.postID
     , wall.inserterID 
     , wall.title 
     , wall.insertDate 
     , wall.editDate 
     , wall.context 
     , user.lastName 
     , cat.catName 
     , wall.catID 
     , pic.picname AS  pic
     , foerID
  FROM wall 
  JOIN user 
    ON user.userID = wall.inserterID 
  JOIN postcategory  cat 
    ON cat.catID = wall.catID 
  LEFT 
  JOIN wallpic pic 
    ON pic.postID = wall.postID 
  LEFT 
  JOIN follow 
    ON follow.foingID = wall.inserterID
 WHERE wall.inserterID != 71
 GROUP 
    BY wall.postID
 ORDER 
    BY follow.foerID IN (71) DESC 
     , wall.insertDate DESC
 LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: What are you asking? What does "it has some problem" mean? What does "improve" mean? If you want a query to be optimised then we need full schema (with indexes) and an `EXPLAIN` of the current query. If its broken, explain why.

Comment: I want to something like facebook newsfeed, improve in this case means that any thing that helps me :), and my query do not return expected result, for example: follower followed two persons with ID of 70 and 2 and I want to return posts which hast this two inserterID at the top of other, but it returns some other posts which has inserted with other persons, not 70 and 1. could I clear things? or should explain more?

Comment: You're misusing the MySQL `GROUP BY` extension. This makes it impossible for both us and the server to tell what you're trying to do. Please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @AndySavage please look at the explanation above

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. This is not going to go well :-(